# Why in some language findIndex return -1?

Tags: arrays

I'm looking into error handling approach in different languages. `Array.findIndex` and `Array.find` are behaving quite differently when item is non exist. `find` method is more consistent to return a `null/undefined` value or throw exception. But in some language `findIndex` return `-1` to indicate missing value. My question is, is there any benefit to return `-1`?

In case where this error is not handled like `collection[items.findIndex("non-exist")]` it can easily cause run time error, so what am I missing here?

**Edit**:
To be more specific, if a language support exception, why in some language still return `-1` instead of throw?

Comment: @Mat I understand this is type consistent but if a language support both `findIndex` and `find` then `find` function must have some form of `null` value.

Comment: At best we can speculate as to the reasons any one language designer or design committee made a choice as to whether to return -1 or null or undefined or "fruit-cake" in the event of not finding an element in an array.

Comment: By `null` I don't mean null value per se, is a form of language support of error handling. I'm confused on why `find` and `findIndex` use different way to represent error?

Comment: It's because `find` and `findIndex` are not doing the same thing. The former is supposed to return an element from the array while the latter returns only an index. While we cannot assume any type of return value from `find`, we can easily assume that the return type from `findIndex` will be a number because array indexes are numbers. If `findIndex` would return non-number value if an element does not exist, then when checking if a value exist we would need to cast the return value to a number (eg. in Java) and see if that succeded. So there is always something we need to check before using it

Answer (score 1):

In some strongly typed languages (Java, C, etc) it makes sense because a `findIndex` function may only be able to return integers.

In those cases is preferred to return -1 instead of throwing an error because not finding something is not an error per se. It might be in your specific case but very often it is just normal and expected. Imagine you're doing an e-mail login form and parsing an input field that expects an e-mail and you want to check if the user is using the full e-mail name (*johndoe@email.com*) or not (*johndoe*). It's not an error if the user doesn't type the *@email.com* as you can just fill it for him.

**edit:** Plus, even in some weakly type languages it might still be desired to have the consistency of always returning an integer. Maybe you want to do arithmetic operations with the result and in that language `if(i >= 3)` would throw an error if `i` is undefined or null

Answer (score 1):

In most languages, `-1` is a number that cannot represent an array index. Therefore, if `.findIndex()` method returns `-1` it means that there is no such element **for sure** and you can perform an easy check like

```
if (array.findIndex(...) == -1)
    // an element does not exist in the array
```

to determine whether an element exists in the array or not.

Following your logic and applying it to your example, if the `.findIndex()` would return `null`/`undefined` or throw an exception, then your example usage

```
collection[items.findIndex("non-exist")]
```

would fail the same way as if `.findIndex()` would return `-1` because neither `null` nor `undefined` can be an array index so this line would throw an exception which we would need to handle. If the `.findIndex()` would throw exceptions when the element does not exist, then... we would also have to handle the exception. So as you can see, you would have to handle the exception anyway.

Another reason for returning `-1` instead of null or throwing an exception, is that in languages such as Java it is not possible to return `null` from a method which is supposed to return a number. However, `.find()` is meant to return an element from the array which may be anything, therefore returning `null` kinda makes sense if it's not expected for your array to contain null-values. In such a case you can assume that an element does not exist if a return value is `null`.

Comment: I'm not concerning type consistency, there are language have exceptions or union types or type classes like `Maybe` or `Option` but are still return `-1` as missing value. So I thought it must be some benefit using -1 over other approach.

Comment: I think the value from union type or type class return type is it's force you to handle error case whereas a `-1` or exception can be silent bypass and cause runtime error later on.